# How to pass column name as well as Table Name to a stored procedure as a parameter in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure which takes the column name as well as the table name as a parameter.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_TableReporting_GetColumnNamesAndValues]
    @concatstring AS VARCHAR(100),
    @Tablename as VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @concatstring FROM @Tablename
END
```

This procedure gives me an error :

> Must declare the scalar variable @TableName

although I have already declared it on the top.

Comment: you hv to use dynamic sql

Comment: The error *should* say that you must declare the *table* variable `@TableName` rather than saying *scalar* variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use dynamic SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_TableReporting_GetColumnNamesAndValues]
@concatstring AS VARCHAR(100),
@Tablename as VARCHAR(100)

AS
BEGIN
    Declare @mystring varchar(max) = N'select ' +  @concatstring + ' from ' + @Tablename
    exec (@mystring)

END
```

Comment: It gives me error
Procedure execution failed
42000 - [SQL Server]Could not find stored procedure 'select Axis from ChamberTest'.