# C# MySQL parameter addwithvalue on SELECT ip,estado FROM @table don't work

Tags: c#, mysql, parameters

I have a method "LeerTabla" on C# class that giving the table name on MySQL database it bring back the ip and estado columns, I tryed parameters with no luck:

First with AddWithValue, calling the method with "secot" `obj.LeerTabla("secot")`:

```
    public void LeerTabla(string NombreTabla)
    {
        string SQLCmdStr;
        try
        {
            SQLCmdStr = "SELECT ip, estado FROM @tabla";
            MySqlCommand SQLcmd = new MySqlCommand(SQLCmdStr, SqlDBconn);
            SQLcmd.Prepare();
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tabla", NombreTabla);
            MySqlDataReader SQLReader = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader();

            while(SQLReader.Read())
            {
                TablaDeIP.Add(SQLReader["ip"].ToString());
                ListaDeEstado.Add(SQLReader["estado"].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Then with Add:

```
public void LeerTabla(string NombreTabla)
{
    string SQLCmdStr;
    try
    {
        SQLCmdStr = "SELECT ip, estado FROM @tabla";
        MySqlCommand SQLcmd = new MySqlCommand(SQLCmdStr, SqlDBconn);
        MySqlParameter parametro = new MySqlParameter();
        parametro.ParameterName = "@tabla";
        parametro.Value = NombreTabla;
        SQLcmd.Parameters.Add(parametro);
        MySqlDataReader SQLReader = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader();

        while(SQLReader.Read())
        {
            TablaDeIP.Add(SQLReader["ip"].ToString());
            ListaDeEstado.Add(SQLReader["estado"].ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Both gave me the same exeption: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near "secot" at line 1"...

But if I don't use parameters it work OK:

```
    public void LeerTabla(string NombreTabla)
    {
        string SQLCmdStr;
        try
        {
            SQLCmdStr = "SELECT ip, estado FROM secot";
            MySqlCommand SQLcmd = new MySqlCommand(SQLCmdStr, SqlDBconn);
            SQLcmd.Prepare();
            MySqlDataReader SQLReader = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader();

            while(SQLReader.Read())
            {
                TablaDeIP.Add(SQLReader["ip"].ToString());
                ListaDeEstado.Add(SQLReader["estado"].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong? any help would be great.

Comment: You are using `@table` for a table name, not for a parameter. Your final example is fine because there is no way for a user to replace the table name. If that is what you want, consult [table name ... as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008233/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters are intended to use with values, not table names. Therefore, you can't parameterize table names in query string like values do.

The most common way to provide dynamic table name is concatenating table name into query string, but this approach still prone to SQL injection:

```
SQLCmdStr = string.Format("SELECT ip, estado FROM {0}", NombreTabla);
```

If you want to use whitelist for table names, use a stored procedure that pass table name as parameter and perform whitelisting by checking table name against `information_schema.tables`:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE RunSQLWithDynamicTableName(@tableName varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @validTableName varchar(50)
    DECLARE @queryString varchar(100)

    SET @validTableName = SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
                          WHERE table_schema = '[database_name]' 
                          AND table_name = @tableName LIMIT 1

    IF @validTableName IS NULL
        # table name does not exist, throw exception here

    # concatenate table name and prepared query string
    SET @queryString = SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @validTableName) 

    PREPARE stmt FROM @queryString
    EXECUTE stmt
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Then call the procedure in `MySqlCommand` query string:

```
SQLCmdStr = "CALL RunSQLWithDynamicTableName(@tableName)"

MySqlCommand SQLcmd = new MySqlCommand(SQLCmdStr, SqlDBconn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@tableName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = NombreTabla;
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I don't know that I can pass a table name as a parameter, also I will try your solution thanks again.

Comment: This is a better answer than those given in the duplicate question [table name ... as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008233/); you should consider adding it there as well.